# When redirecting to an url I am getting invalid Xframe options only in chrome

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://etc....': 'ALLOW' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example....' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://home.etc...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.